# How to override Publishing Path while publishing?

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, web8.5, legacy-pack

In our upgrade from 2013 to 8.5 We want to be able to clean up the Publish Path to remove numbers and chaff from the path.

To do this We need to be able to have two different publishing paths, one for publishing to the legacy 2013 publishing targets with the very long and windy names with numbers and old site names path and one for publishing to new Business Process Type Targets with new short meaningful names.

Is it possible to publish to two different file paths without creating child publications?

Answer (score -1):

In general, it is not a best practice to create a child publication unless there needs to be localization of content or design elements. If you need to publish to a new location, you will typically have to create a new target for the publication.

Tridion will not allow you to map the business process type unless the publication path of your publication matches the context url or the url path segment of the defined topology. Your publication should therefore have your new path or an empty one.

Have you considered a URLRewrite solution to basically rewrite the old context with the new context? If you are using a DotNet implementation, you can consider a [UrlRewrite.Net](https://github.com/Bikeman868/UrlRewrite.Net). This would help you achieve your solution seamlessly.

You can consider having a storage extension, if you were publishing to a filesystem earlier. There could be some potential issues with Tridion linking though. I strongly feel that you can achieve it via URL manipulation though.